# How do I install the latest version of ubuntu touch in a LG Nexus 4?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I installed ubuntu on the touch device LG NEXUS 4 according to the instructions of the wiki. The first problem was the command in step 4:

```
phablet-flash (cdimage-touch | cdimage-legacy | ubuntu-system | community)-b
```

gave me:

```
(bash: syntax error near token expected "cdimage-touch")
```

I got results only when I separate the commands and I fired one at a time:

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch-b
phablet cdimage-flash-legacy-b
```

But while the first left on the android device, the second has installed a version of ubuntu that is not like those visible in several movies on the internet, for example does not have the ability to upgrade the system from the app settings.

I tried to update the system from the terminal, but the next time the OS crashed and then after a reboot of the system are no longer started (remained a black screen).
I restored Android and I redid the same procedures but got the same result, the system was unstable and often got stuck.

Is there any way to flash with the command phablet-flash the latest release of ubuntu touch?

My P.C. has Kubuntu operating system

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to run `phablet-flash` with the appropriate selection from

> (cdimage-touch | cdimage-legacy | ubuntu-system | community)

So for a Nexus 4 you would do either:

```
phablet-flash cdimage-touch
```

or

```
phablet-flash ubuntu-system
```

It is four choices for you to chose based upon the device you have and what you are trying to do.

Comment: I upgraded my operating system and I ran the command "phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b".
The command has downloaded a new image 20130905.1 dated and then it programmed into the device.
I used the phone and now ubuntu touch seems to be more advanced.
I have also been able to launch the update check on the settings of the phone.
Then I ran the command "phablet-image ubuntu-system", after I ran the command "adb shell reboot" and started with ubuntu touch.
The Update screen now tells me I'm the latest version.
Thank you, best regards.